# React/Truffle: How to call a function with passing a variable?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, react

I have a React component within which a web3js function queries numbers from Ethereum by using `getNumber()` function.

I want to call another function called `setNumber()` that takes one `uint256`, by passing to it the output that I'm getting from `getNumber()`. What would be the best way to do that in Truffle/React?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the best way for it :
consider your contract name is `contract` and then

first you must get your accounts from web3 lib :

`let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()`

for setting a number use : 
`await contract.methods.setNumber('your number').send({from : accounts[0]})`

and for get a number use : 
`let number = contract.methods.getNumber().call()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But how to put the output from getNumber() to setNumber()?

Comment: simple like this :    `let number = contract.methods.getNumber().call()` and after that `await contract.methods.setNumber(number).send({from : accounts[0]})`